# PHP Nested While loop not working with mysql_fetch_assoc

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I tested looping nested While statements so:

```
$count1 = 0;

while ($count1 < 3) {
 $count1++;
 $count2 = 0;
 echo "count1: ".$count1."<br />";

    while ($count2 < 3) {
    $count2++;
    echo "count2: ".$count2."<br />";
    }
}
```

This works perfectly (looping three times each) with results:

```
count1: 1
 count2: 1
 count2: 2
 count2: 3
count1: 2
 count2: 1
 count2: 2
 count2: 3
count1: 3
 count2: 1
 count2: 2
 count2: 3
```

Then I tried the same with a loop using mysql_fetch_assoc ($ContactsInterests is a two row associative array, and $LatestNews has 50 rows) i.e.

```
$CI_count = 0;

while ($CI_Row = mysql_fetch_assoc($ContactsInterests)) { //loop thru interests
$CI_count++;
$LN_count = 0;
echo "CI_count: ".$CI_count."<br />";

while ($LN_Row = mysql_fetch_assoc($LatestNews)) { //loop thru news
    $LN_count++;
    echo "LN_count: ".$LN_count."<br />";

}
}
```

The results are:

```
CI_count: 1
 LN_count: 1
 LN_count: 2
 ...
 LN_count: 50
 LN_count: 51
CI_count: 2
```

But where it the second iteration of LN_count?  I don't understand why the LN_count didn't increment a second time.

Help appreciated.

Comment: at the top add $LN_Row = array();
Then, at the end of the first while loop add reset($LN_Row);

Comment: @redskins80 the `$LN_Row` contains only the last value passed by `mysql_fetch_assoc`... so it won't fill up the `$LN_Row` unless you do something like this `$LN_Row[] = mysql_fetch_assoc`

Comment: @Dexter youre right! ive deleted my answer. sry.

Comment: STOP USING THE mySQL_* EXTENSIONS IMMEDIATELY. They are being deprecated. Use either PDO our the I extensions.

Comment: Don't worry guys, @Jeremy is probably sleeping by now, he's not responding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[mysql_fetch_assoc](http://us.php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc) does iteration for "mysql result" type. Seeks index for each fetch. 
you must use [mysql_data_seek](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-data-seek.php) to go to the first result like;

```
<?php

    $CI_count = 0;

    while ($CI_Row = mysql_fetch_assoc($ContactsInterests)) { //loop thru interests
        $CI_count++;
        $LN_count = 0;
        echo "CI_count: ".$CI_count."<br />";

        mysql_data_seek($LatestNews,0);
        while ($LN_Row = mysql_fetch_assoc($LatestNews)) { //loop thru news
            $LN_count++;
            echo "LN_count: ".$LN_count."<br />";

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the results have been exhausted. You've iterated through all of them... If you wanted to loop again you're have to repopulate the $LatestNews variable.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_fetch_assoc()`  takes out one by one the rows of the source, you when you will be in the second step of the first loop, you wont have any rows in the source variable.

You need to put the results of the second query in an array, then loop the array, and not using mysql_fetch_assoc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the mysql internal pointer:

see http://php.net/mysql_data_seek